# Turn off data annotation validation for a property that is itself a view model, given a certain condition on the parent view model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am constructing a page using Editor Templates and composition.  My view model contains properties which are themselves view models.  E.g.

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public boolean SomeCheckBox { get; set; }

    public ChildModel Child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel
{
    [Required]
    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string SomeOtherString { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the data annotation validation to kick in on the child only if the property SomeCheckBox on the parent is true.

I've seen a RequiredIf custom validation attribute elsewhere on stackoverflow, however it only works when the condition is a value of the same view model.  I need something that can check the parent, or indeed a property on an ancestor.

My temporary hack is to clear the ModelState errors on postback if the checkbox isn't true.

I've also had to write some custom javascript so that the client browser suppresses the validation if the checkbox isn't ticked.

The real example is much more complicated than this but hopefully it's clear from the above simplified example what I'm after.

What would be nice is an attribute on the parent view model that is something like

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public boolean SomeCheckBox { get; set; }

    [SuppressValidationIf("SomeCheckBox", false)]
    public ChildModel Child { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This excellent example perfectly illustrates the limitations of doing declarative validation which is what data annotations are.

It's for this reason that I would recommend you using an imperative approach for your validation rules as you can handle many scenarios. [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) is a great example of a library which would have rendered this validation scenario a piece of cake.

Let me illustrate how it could handle this scenario:

We start by defining validators for our child and parent models:

```
public class ChildModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ChildModel>
{
    public ChildModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.SomeString).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.SomeOtherString).NotEmpty();
    }
}

public class ParentModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ParentModel>
{
    public ParentModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Child)
            .SetValidator(new ChildModelValidator())
            .When(x => x.SomeCheckBox);
    }
}
```

Notice how the child validator is included based on the value of the `SomeCheckBox` property on the parent? Now your models would look like this:

```
[Validator(typeof(ParentModelValidator))]
public class ParentModel
{
    public bool SomeCheckBox { get; set; }
    public ChildModel Child { get; set; }
}

public class ChildModel
{
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherString { get; set; }
}
```

And that's all.

You simply install the `FluentValidation.MVC3` NuGet, add the following line in `Application_Start`:

```
FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure();
```

and now you work as usual:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new ParentModel
        {
            Child = new ChildModel()
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ParentModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and a view:

```
@model ParentModel

@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SomeCheckBox)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Child.SomeString)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Child.SomeOtherString)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

If the checkbox is checked the child validator will kick in and require the 2 properties.

Comment: That looks interesting, thanks Darin - I'll take a look at FluentValidation.Net

Comment: Hey Darin, I'm trying this out now - it works really well server side, however there's a minor snag in that it doesn't produce client side javascript for validators that include a .When() condition.  They mention the same on here http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc.  Do you happen to know if anyone has written an extension for the client side script to support the .When() condition?  Or do you normally write custom validation script for your pages?  Cheers, Tony

Comment: @TonyLeeper, for such custom validation logic I write custom client validation scripts.